# Why doesn't Xamarin hit breakpoints when set to build as debug?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

This is a Xamarin.Forms solution and I'm currently building for UWP. This is a small, fairly new solution. I'm having a few problems with the debugger:

1. When build is set to debug breakpoints aren't hit.
2. When set to release, breakpoints are hit but it downloads something for about five minutes before it finishes the build. It does this every time so it's not caching whatever its downloading.
3. Setting a breakpoint in the body of a Command's CanExecute method moves you to a file called Adapters.g.cs and sets the breakpoint on a method there. I've never seen anything like that before. Also, that only happens when I have it set to release. It does nothing at all when set to debug.

I haven't changed any platform-specific configuration settings. It just doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: Just found the answer. - go to the shared project > Go to Build > Advanced... Set Debug Information to Full -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/debugger-settings - Shouldn't that be the default!?

Comment: post your steps as answer.

Answer (score 2):

For my situation it was resolved by following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/debugger-settings).

1. Go to the shared project.
   [image]
2. Go to Build > Advanced... Set Debug Information to Full

---

It added this to the .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
  <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
</PropertyGroup>
```